# org.xml.sax.SAXException: No tag "outputScript" defined in tag library associated with uri "http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

After updating from JSF 1.2 to JSF 2.0  we faced a problem that there is no JSF 2.0 tags can be found in the tags library. in spite of removing all JSF 1.2 dependencies (replacing `scope compile` to `scope provided` in common projects but there are still depend on JSF 1.2 but with `scope provided`) it doesn't work anyway.

The StackTrace:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXException: No tag "outputScript" defined in tag library associated with uri "http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JspDocumentParser.parseCustomAction(JspDocumentParser.java:1179)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JspDocumentParser.startElement(JspDocumentParser.java:400)
    org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JspDocumentParser.parse(JspDocumentParser.java:174)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:239)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:103)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:185)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:354)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:334)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:321)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:592)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:328)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.dispatch(ExternalContextImpl.java:568)
    javax.faces.context.ExternalContextWrapper.dispatch(ExternalContextWrapper.java:93)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.executePageToBuildView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:363)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:153)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:99)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doForward(PageContextImpl.java:709)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.forward(PageContextImpl.java:680)
    org.apache.jsp.home_jsp._jspx_meth_security_005fauthorize_005f1(home_jsp.java:131)
    org.apache.jsp.home_jsp._jspService(home_jsp.java:64)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:378)
    org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
    org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    org.springframework.security.ui.SessionFixationProtectionFilter.doFilterHttp(SessionFixationProtectionFilter.java:67)
    org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    org.springframework.security.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilterHttp(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:101)
    org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    org.springframework.security.wrapper.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilterHttp(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:91)
    org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    org.springframework.security.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:277)
    org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    org.springframework.security.ui.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilterHttp(LogoutFilter.java:89)
    org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    org.springframework.security.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilterHttp(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:235)
    org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:175)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:236)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
```

Here is my web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>  
     <param-name>javax.faces.DISABLE_FACELET_JSF_VIEWHANDLER</param-name>  
     <param-value>true</param-value>  
</context-param>  

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.application.CONFIG_FILES</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
    <param-value>.jspx</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.validateXml</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>facelets.DEVELOPMENT</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/applicationContext-admin-dao.xml
        /WEB-INF/applicationContext-admin-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.skin</param-name>
    <param-value>emeraldTown</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.enableControlSkinning</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.sendPoweredByHeader</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/j_spring_security_check</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>

<!--<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>-->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.security.ui.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>context</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
</session-config>

<!--<error-page>
<error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/404.html</location>
</error-page>-->
<error-page>
    <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
    <location>/index.jsp</location>
</error-page>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

mvn dependency:tree give the following

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building admin 1.25
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ admin ---
[INFO] +- net.kencochrane.raven:raven:jar:5.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.4.2:compile
[INFO] +- net.kencochrane.raven:raven-log4j2:jar:5.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.testng:testng:jar:jdk15:4.7:test
[INFO] |  +- qdox:qdox:jar:1.5:test
[INFO] |  \- bsh:bsh:jar:2.0b1:test
[INFO] +- jdbcappender:jdbcappender:jar:2.1.01:compile
[INFO] +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2:compile
[INFO] +- commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:jar:1.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
[INFO] +- commons-discovery:commons-discovery:jar:0.4:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:provided
[INFO] +- javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:jar:2.1:provided
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:jstl:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.sun.faces:jsf-api:jar:2.1.29-01:compile
[INFO] +- com.sun.faces:jsf-impl:jar:2.1.29-01:compile
[INFO] +- el-impl:el-impl:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.5.3:compile
[INFO] +- aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.5.3:compile
[INFO] +- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.9.1:compile
[INFO] +- jfree:jcommon:jar:1.0.12:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:2.5.5:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:2.5.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:2.5.5:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:2.5.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-dao:jar:2.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:2.5.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-support:jar:2.0.8:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:2.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:2.5.5:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-taglibs:jar:2.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-acl:jar:2.0.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:3.3.1.GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-annotations:jar:3.4.0.GA:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.hibernate:ejb3-persistence:jar:1.0.2.GA:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:3.3.0.ga:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate:jar:3.2.1.ga:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- asm:asm-attrs:jar:1.5.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- cglib:cglib:jar:2.1_3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- asm:asm:jar:1.5.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.persistence:persistence-api:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- el-functors:el-functors:jar:1.0.3:runtime
[INFO] +- javassist:javassist:jar:3.10.0.GA:runtime
[INFO] +- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.richfaces:richfaces:jar:4.5.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.richfaces:richfaces-core:jar:4.5.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.sourceforge.cssparser:cssparser:jar:0.9.14:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.w3c.css:sac:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.google.guava:guava:jar:18.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.richfaces:richfaces-a4j:jar:4.5.2.Final:compile
[INFO] +- postgresql:postgresql:jar:8.3-603.jdbc4:runtime
[INFO] +- javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4.1:compile
[INFO] +- quartz:quartz:jar:1.5.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.freemarker:freemarker:jar:2.3.9:compile
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.5:test
[INFO] +- avalon-framework:avalon-framework:jar:4.1.3:compile
[INFO] +- com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj:saaj-impl:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.xml.soap:saaj-api:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] +- javax.annotation:jsr250-api:jar:1.0:compile
```

Comment: Your web.xml file still indicates `jsp`, `jspx` and `html` extensions. Even `FacesServlet` is mapped to the `*.html` pattern. In JSF 2.0, you need to use Facelets as a view technology which uses tags like `<h:head>, <h:body>, <h:outputStylesheet>, <h:outputScript>`, `<f:xxx>`, `<ui:xxx>` etc. I never used JSF 1.x but to a guess, these tags may not exist in ancient JSP as a view technology. Hence, the exception. You need to adopt Facelets (which is typically an XHTML file) and make changes to the code accordingly.

Comment: @Tiny So how can I correct my `web.xml`?  What should I do?