# Is it ever possible to use jspx file extension with JSF 2.1?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, jspx

My problem is the following. Our project was initially written in `JSF 1.2` with `.jspx` file extensions. Now, when I make migartion from JSF 1.2 to JSF 2.1 I came across the problem about using JSF 2.0 tags in the `jspx` pages. So, `web.xml`:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
    <param-value>.jspx</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And when I try to use  I get the error:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXException: PWC6143: No tag "head" defined in tag library associated with uri "http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JspDocumentParser.parseCustomAction(JspDocumentParser.java:1183)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JspDocumentParser.startElement(JspDocumentParser.java:429)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JspDocumentParser.parse(JspDocumentParser.java:203)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:208)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:124)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:184)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:409)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:592)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:344)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:470)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:364)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1221)
    at ua.com.winforce.loto_partner.admin.filter.EncodingFilter.doFilter(EncodingFilter.java:14)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:399)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:766)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:450)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:928)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:549)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:410)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

But, when I replace `.jspx` file extension and `javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX` param with `xhtml` or any other extension it will work fine. I also tried to set:

```
 <context-param>
    <param-name>DEFAULT_FACELETS_SUFFIX </param-name>
    <param-value>.jspx</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>FACELETS_SUFFIX_PARAM_NAME</param-name>
    <param-value>.jspx</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>DEFAULT_SUFFIX_PARAM_NAME</param-name>
    <param-value>.jspx</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>FACELETS_VIEW_MAPPINGS_PARAM_NAME</param-name>
    <param-value>.jspx</param-value>
</context-param>
```

***Question***: Should I neccesary replace `.jspx` extension with say, `xhtml` or `jsf` or any aother extension in order to use all `JSF2` capabilities?

Comment: You are experiencing the problem which is somewhat similar to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28515740/1391249).

Comment: See JSF 2.1 spec appendix A. In JSF 2 jsp was deprecated and replaced by facelets, but in 2.1 there was a modification to allow parse .jspx files with facelets compiler. Please note not every jsp tag exists in facelets.